# logcat doesn't display logs from library project in my special case

Tags: android, performance, logcat, android-logcat, library-project

I have three Android projects: **BaseLibProject**, **MainLibProject**, **AppProject**.

The relationship of these three Android projects is that:

1. The **BaseLibProject** is a library project used by **MainLibProject**.
2. The **MainLibProject** uses **BaseLibProject** as library project, and generates **MainLib.jar**(use maven build)
3. The generated **MainLib.jar**  is added to **AppProject**'s `libs/` folder & also added to the build path of **AppProject**.

**NEXT:**

A simple class in **BaseLibProject** :

```
public class BaseLibClass {
   public static String doBaseTask() {
       Log.i("MyLog", "doBaseTask..."); //I can't see this log
       return "Result from Base!";
   } 
}
```

A simple class in **MainLibProject** which defined a function invokes the function in **BaseLibProject**:

```
public class MainLibClass {
    public static void doMainTask() {
        Log.i("MyLog", "doMainTask..."); //I can see this log in logcat
        String result = BaseLibClass.doBaseTask();
        Log.i("MyLog", "result = " + result); //I can see the result log
    } 
}
```

Finally, in my **AppProject** I simply call above function of **MainLibProject** (remember I have **MainLib.jar**):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MainLibClass.doMainTask();
    }
}
```

I started **logcat** with command `adb logcat -s MyLog:*` . When I run my AppProject application, logcat displays

```
I/MyLog(2039): doMainTask...
I/MyLog(2039): result = Result from Base!
```

According to above log, the code in **BaseLibProject** is running (because I got result from BaseLibClass), but it **doesn't** display any logs from **BaseLibProject**, why???

(I have googled on internect, someone got similar issue fixed by restarting eclipse, but in my case, it doesn't help. Besides, I am checking logs from terminal NOT from eclipse.)

Comment: As described, this would seem "impossible" :) AFAIK, when library projects are merged into an app project, their classes should become indistinguishable from the app's classes. Anyway, have you tried disassembling classes.dex in your apk to check if the `Log.i` call is present in `BaseLibClass.doBaseTask()`?

Comment: @matiash , I dissembled the classes.dex, the Log.i is removed for some reason. But why it is removed? I only added my BaseLibProject as a dependecy in my MainLibProject's pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally, I fixed the problem.

The reason is that in BaseLibProject pom.xml, I defined `<packaging>apk</packaging>`, while in MainLibProject pom.xml, when I define the dependency of BaseLibProject, I didn't specify the `<type>` of the artifact.

After I changed BaseLibProject's pom.xml to `<packagin>apklib</packaging>` and in MainLibProject's pom.xml specified the dependency of BaseLibProject with `<type>apklib</type>` . I am able to see the logs in BaseLibProject.